# Line between a programming puzzle and a programming problem

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons

I've answered many questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions),
 many of which got me to sit down and think in a way like it were an entertaining puzzle!

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61820846/13552470) is an example of such a post.

I want to know where the line is drawn to separate programming puzzles and programming problems (sort of like the line between math puzzles and math problems).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean *on Stack Overflow*, I don't know whether anyone there makes a puzzle/problem distinction or how they make it, and I don't think it's something on which PSE folks can usefully comment.

If you mean *here on Puzzling*, the principle would be the same as for mathematical questions. It's pretty well expressed in [this answer by xnor](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784/19114). Something is a *problem* if its solution is basically routine and involves doing standard things in standard ways; it's a *puzzle* if its solution involves some surprising bit of insight. xnor mentions some other factors, but I think they are rather less important than that.

This principle clearly doesn't entirely capture the difference between puzzles and non-puzzles. A standard newspaper sudoku puzzle can be solved routinely -- it's not hard to write a computer program that does it -- but it's clearly a puzzle. I think part of the reason why is that it's *intended for recreation*, though that's a problematic criterion since it's a fact about whoever made the puzzle rather than about the actual puzzle itself.

For something to count as a programming puzzle and be appropriate here, I think (though this isn't intended to set Official Policy or anything; if it turns out to matter enough to have an official policy, we should debate it more carefully) it should have the following properties.

- Solving it should be *non-routine*. If a good-but-not-exceptional software developer could solve it in half an hour without thinking "aha!" or "wow!" at any point in the process, it's probably not a puzzle.
- It should be *fun*. E.g., if something requires 300 lines of code then it is probably not fun. Any program you have to write for a puzzle should be short and sweet, much shorter than the great majority of nontrivial programs written out in the real world.
- There should be something *particularly nice* about the question or its answer or, even better, both. A particularly elegant algorithmic technique, a bit-twiddling trick that does something much more concisely than one would expect, that sort of thing.

I don't think the turtle-graphics question you link to meets these criteria, though it's within spitting distance.

Many recreational programming challenges would be a better fit for [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) than here. In particular, that's likely true for any challenge like "write *as short a program as you can* that does X" or "write a program that does X *as quickly as possible*".

Also relevant: the [actual official PSE policy on mathematical questions](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6030/proposed-policy-on-mathematical-questions) which, as well as the non-routineness criterion, mentions two others that I think are broadly applicable here: questions should be *comprehensible* to a reasonable fraction of PSE readers, and to whatever extent a question involves domain-specific technicalities there should be a "Puzzling-friendly payoff": some reason why ordinary PSE readers might find it worth looking at despite the technicalities.

Answer (score 6):

I saw (and answered) [your first programming puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/104029/71652). I think it's a good start, and it does fit better on Puzzling than on Code Golf, which moved away from Puzzling-style challenges (those that have one or small number of intended answers). However, as a long-term challenge setter on Code Golf, I have some advice for you (and other potential programming puzzle writers):

### If the puzzle is related to a programming task, define the task as rigorously as possible

This is (IMO) 90% of the reason Code Golfers use the Sandbox.

A programming puzzle can be written in various ways, including but not limited to (minus those that are on-topic on Code Golf):

- complete the blanks to fulfill the given task
- given a wrong program or function that is intended to solve a task, find one-char correction to make it work
- given a program or function that is intended to solve a task, find the input that breaks it

All of these involve **a task** to solve. If it is not well-defined, the readers won't be able to judge whether a given program solves the task or not. One example is the OP's first puzzle (linked above), where the expected result is given as a console output from the `print`. Some example outputs have trailing spaces to make it rectangular, but the last one has part of them truncated. This makes the task not well-defined, and hence my question in the comment ("Are the trailing whitespaces on each row significant?"). Whether they should be printed or it doesn't matter, the task should mention that.

### Try to make a puzzle, not a competition or a bootcamp quiz

As already pointed out by Gareth, competition-style challenges (e.g. "solve it in few bytes as possible") are on-topic on Code Golf, and therefore not suitable to Puzzling. Try to make your puzzle more focused so that it has only one intended answer. A puzzle with a few unintended answers is fine; a puzzle that is too open that it may start a competition between answerers is not.

Also, a puzzle which can be trivially solved with knowledge about basic language features (syntax and built-in functionality) is not a good puzzle either. Introducing seldom used features or hiding it in a clever way *could* be fine.

Comment: A bit late, but: "are on-topic on Code Golf, and therefore not suitable to Puzzling" -- just because something is on-topic on one site doesn't mean it's off-topic on another. (It *is* the case that code-golf-style challenges are off-topic here. But that's because they aren't puzzles, not because of anything to do with the Code Golf site.)