# Should recreational mathematics be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There is an ongoing debate about what sort of questions should be on topic on puzzling.SE. So, let me add to it by asking a specific question. Should recreational mathematics questions be welcome here?

First, let me give some examples of what I mean by recreational mathematics from math.SE.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205953/how-do-you-find-the-center-of-a-circle-with-a-pencil-and-a-book

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481527/slice-of-pizza-with-no-crust

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44684/what-is-the-smallest-number-of-45-circ-60-circ-75-circ-triangles-that-a-squ

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639/logic-problem-identifying-poisoned-wines-out-of-a-sample-minimizing-test-subje

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872942/fun-geometric-series-puzzle

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604824/can-this-ant-find-its-way-back-to-the-nest

All of these should be welcome on puzzling.SE in my view.

A puzzle that requires more than the most elementary University level math, say, could be migrated to math.SE if it doesn't get any good answers on puzzling.SE after a week. I don't think this would apply to any of the questions above however.

**Related questions:**

[Should mathematics questions really be on-topic here?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/should-mathematics-questions-really-be-on-topic-here?rq=1) (about mathematics)

[Is it on-topic to present specific logic puzzles or brainteasers as questions?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/is-it-on-topic-to-present-specific-logic-puzzles-or-brainteasers-as-questions?lq=1) (about whether specific puzzles are on topic)

[Are probability exercises on topic here?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215/are-probability-exercises-on-topic-here) (about probability questions)

Comment: I'm in favour for having them. Only problem; We have to prove we're one site, not just a site with a collection of questions that could exist somewhere else.

Comment: @warspyking We are a puzzle site. This includes all sorts of puzzles and riddles as well as discussion of how to make good puzzles and riddles. That seems clear doesn't it? There is always some overlap between sites but that is natural.

Comment: I know... This seems to overlap way too much math.

Comment: @warspyking I really don't agree. There is a puzzle tag on math.SE but really it is second class citizen to the main business of math.SE. Those people need a home and in many cases the level of math knowledge needed to enjoy recreational mathematics is nothing above high school.  I do agree that math puzzles which require advanced University level math are most likely off topic as I suggested in my question.

Comment: still hasn't been answered!? do you think it's a duplicate Lembik?

Comment: @d'alar'cop It's not the same question although clearly closely related. In particular, the relevant question is about recreational mathematics in my view and not general mathematics.  Recreational mathematics almost never involves advanced mathematics as I have attempted to demonstrate.

Comment: Ok in that case I'll write an answer within the next day (unless you do it first)

Comment: The answer linked to by the close comment is written by me! Does this make sense?  Aren't we looking for multiple answers from the community?