# Can we ask difficult math puzzles here?

Tags: support, scope

Can we ask difficult math questions here?  More specifically, I mean a math question that involves square roots.

Comment: You and I have a different idea of what counts as a difficult math question. Are you trying to dump your homework on us?

Comment: No.  I have solved a rather interesting olympiad problem.  Is this a place to share about the problem? @JohnDvorak

Comment: @XcoderX Yes, that sounds fine. Just remember to include a citation to where you found the problem :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, as long as they really are "puzzles".

We have a lot of [mathematics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) puzzles on this site - nearly 2000 questions in the tag - and many of them are Olympiad-style questions, some even taken from actual Olympiads. Square roots certainly aren't considered "difficult maths" by this site's standards - we've even had a puzzle whose solution required using the Green-Tao theorem!

A few ***important*** caveats though, before you post your puzzle:

- **Maths *puzzles* are on-topic; maths *problems* are not.** See [Are math-textbook-style problems on topic?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2783/5373) for our explanation of the difference between the two. Basically, your puzzle needs to be somehow "interesting" and not formulaic.
- **Puzzles involving *very* advanced maths may be frowned upon.** For more details on this rather nebulous policy, see [What tricky mathematical questions are on topic here?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6022/5373) and [Proposed policy on mathematical questions](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6030/5373). Basically, the puzzle (not necessarily the solution) should be at least comprehensible to a reasonable subset of Puzzling users. Again, square roots are definitely way below that bar, and I suspect all Olympiad questions easily pass this criterion. Just don't post something which requires a deep understanding of the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem ;-)
- **You *must* cite your source.** If you're taking a puzzle from an actual olympiad, or a similar competition, or a puzzle book, remember to state in the body of your question where you found it. Without this acknowledgement, your question runs the risk of being deleted for 'plagiarism'.

Comment: is [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89362/find-the-hidden-message-in-this-weird-array/89363#89362) question okay?

Comment: @Scratch---Cat I see no reason why it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

There's certainly no objection to square roots, and plenty of questions have been asked here that involve some quite tricky mathematics. However, PSE tends to frown on questions that are *mathematics problems* as opposed to *mathematical puzzles*. Roughly, the question to be asking is: is this more *something you might solve for fun* or *the sort of exercise you'd find in a textbook or mathematics class homework*?

Take a look at [the "mathematics" tag](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics?sort=newest) to get an idea of the sort of mathematical question that gets asked here (and which ones have received lots of upvotes or good answers).

Comment: Okay... by mathematics can it be sort of like olympiad style?

Comment: Some of the mathematics-tagged questions here are quite olympiad-ish, yes. Anything at IMO level or above is going to be accessible only to a small fraction of Puzzling participants (though we *do* have a bunch of IMO types here). There isn't universal agreement on whether that's a problem or not. (Personally, I enjoy such questions but am on the fence as to whether they're appropriate here.)